# Having trouble deserializing a json array to a c# list

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

There are so many json serializing/deserializing options, so I'm not sure which one is the correct one to use, and why there are so many options to do seemingly the same thing. I've seen JsonConvert, JsonSerializer, JavaScriptSerializer, and several others.

Looking for help on correctly deserializng a json array into a c# list of complex objects.

JQUERY:

```
 var users = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) 
    {
        var u = 
        {
            Id: response[i].id,
            UserName: response[i].username,
            FirstName: response[i].first_name,
            LastName: response[i].last_name    
        };
        users[i] = u;
    }

    var ul = JSON.stringify({ 'userlist': users});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myurl/addusers",
        data: { 'userlist': ul },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {  

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

        }
    });
```

C# (this doesn't work):

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddUsers(string userlist)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var users = ser.Deserialize<List<User>>(userlist); 
            ...
        }  

    [Serializable]
    public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if/how it fits with MVC but .NET Web API already does all this functionality for you. You should look into making use of that. http://www.asp.net/web-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var ul = JSON.stringify({ 'userlist': users});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myurl/addusers",
        data: ul ,
        content-Type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {  

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

        }
    });
```

You already are setting `userlist` in the  json `ul` so just asign it directly to data without wrapping it over `userlist` again, also set the contentType `content-Type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` in the ajax settings.

Also in your action just use:

```
    public ActionResult AddUsers(List<User> userlist)
    {
     //no need to do JavaScriptSerializer
```

Comment: This is actually what I had initially.  I tried this again, however, I'm getting a count of 0 in my userlist when AddUsers gets called. Btw, thanks for pointing out the mistake in the jquery.  I've corrected that.

Comment: @Prabhu Check in your network console (chrome) in the browser to see how the data goes out. Also add  `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, See my update

Comment: @Prabhu you are welcome. I did not notice that initially in your code, later i realized you had missed that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your action to accept List of users, the model binder will take care of the rest, like that:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddUsers(List<User> users)
        {
            //use the 
        }
```

Change javascript to send the users array directly, without surrogate property:

```
var ul = JSON.stringify(users);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myurl/addusers",
        data: ul ,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {  

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this also (similar to PSL's method), but I'm still seeing a count of 0 items when AddUsers gets called, even though there is one item in ul.